# Mule VM configurations in cluster with two nodes

Tags: mule, load-balancing

I have UseCase as below:

Currently I have setted up mule-ha cluster environment. One physical system will contain mmc and server 1 and other physical machine contains the server 2.Able to establish a cluster environment and verified messages are getting processed in both servers.

Currently I am facing a problem whenever my flows contains an VM outbound and other flow is having VM as inbound(pointing to same Queue).

I have a flow with http as inbound (req-res) and logger and VM outbound(One-way) .Other flow contains the VM inbound(one-way) and logger.

When ever i am invoking the flow from soap or jmeter tool all the logs are filled up in the physical machine where http inbound Ip is pointing

in more detail: If I give IP in http inbound of server 1 then logs are filled in Server 1,
if I give IP in http inbound of server 2 then logs are filled in Server 2.

Can some one suggest me whether any specific configuration to be implemented for VM specific flows?

Tried with VM connector too but same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for the node that do not receive the HTTP request to process the requests? I mean, are you loading your app enough so the VM contains more than one message? In the scenario you describe probably the second flow (the one with vm-inbound) will consume messages faster than the firs flow (the http-inbound). So, there is no need for the other node to consume messages. Perhaps you could try generating a higher load or making some processing in the second flow. Something like:

```
<scripting:transformer>
    <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>
```

But I recommend you to try a real world scenario for verifying clustering behaviour.